# usb-ethernet not negotiating link automatically

Tags: usb, ethernet

Device in question: lsusb tells me ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8153 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
This is a Monoprice branded USB-A 3 adapter.

Running Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

In network manager, the connection says Speed: 1 GB/s

When I plug this USB-Ethernet device into a gig switch, that works fine.

But I frequently plug into devices that only support 100 Mbit. When I do, I get:

```
# mii-tool enx00e04c680835
enx00e04c680835: 10 Mbit, full duplex, no link
```

If I force it, it will eventually get a dhcp address and stay on the network at 100 Mbit, but if I only run `mii-tool --force=100baseTx-FD enx00e04c680835` once, it'll momentarily say `enx00e04c680835: 100 Mbit, full duplex, no link` but then revert to `10...no link`

Sometimes I get lucky and it'll work first time, but usually it takes several tries before it flips to "link ok". i.e. if I run mii-tool every second:

```
enx00e04c680835: 10 Mbit, full duplex, no link
enx00e04c680835: 10 Mbit, full duplex, no link
enx00e04c680835: 100 Mbit, full duplex, no link
enx00e04c680835: 100 Mbit, full duplex, no link
enx00e04c680835: 100 Mbit, full duplex, no link
enx00e04c680835: 10 Mbit, full duplex, no link
enx00e04c680835: 10 Mbit, full duplex, no link
enx00e04c680835: 10 Mbit, full duplex, no link
enx00e04c680835: 100 Mbit, full duplex, no link
enx00e04c680835: 100 Mbit, full duplex, no link
enx00e04c680835: 100 Mbit, full duplex, link ok
enx00e04c680835: 100 Mbit, full duplex, link ok
```

As requested:

```
# lsmod | fgrep r815
r8152                  69632  0
mii                    20480  3 usbnet,r8152,ax88179_178a
```

dmesg during insertion:

```
# dmesg >/tmp/0
# echo Insert dongle
# dmesg >/tmp/1
# diff -U0 /tmp/[01]
+[  198.076807] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
+[  198.097308] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=8153, bcdDevice=30.00
+[  198.097314] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=6
+[  198.097318] usb 2-1: Product: USB 10/100/1000 LAN
+[  198.097322] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Realtek
+[  198.097325] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 000001000000
+[  198.118095] usbcore: registered new interface driver r8152
+[  198.124378] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ether
+[  198.245331] usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
+[  198.297994] r8152 2-1:1.0 eth0: v1.10.11
+[  198.319976] r8152 2-1:1.0 enx00e04c680835: renamed from eth0
+[  200.490820] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enx00e04c680835: link becomes ready
+[  200.491241] r8152 2-1:1.0 enx00e04c680835: carrier on
+[  200.525194] r8152 2-1:1.0 enx00e04c680835: carrier off
```

Repeatability: I have two of these dongles, and the bad behaviour is consistent across both of them, so it's a software issue, not a hardware one. I also tried an Apple-branded USB-A to 100 Mbit dongle, and that works. I also tried a "USB-A 3 hub with ethernet" from Monoprice, and that works without need for mii-tool either.

This started happening a few months ago; it used to work just fine. Did something change in the driver? in Network Manager? I'm stumped what is messing with my device.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of: `lsmod | grep r815` and: `sudo dmesg | grep r815`

Comment: Sorry for the delay; added. I wanted to reboot so I had a clean system

Comment: Please see: "carrier off; carrier on" in the message log. Are you certain that you are using a known good cable?

Comment: @chili555 I am absolutely sure it's not a cable or the device, on either end. I have tested with half a dozen different 100Mbit devices, two different usb-ethernet dongles, and at least a dozen ethernet cables. Note also that as per the description, it works just fine when I use mii-tool --force=100baseTx-FD (though it takes a few tries, because something else keeps resetting it to 10BT)